# Windows System Programming OpenFile function

Tags: c++, windows

The documentation for OpenFile function in Windows is located [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365430%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). And I am trying to do this:

```
#include "Tchar.h"
#include <windows.h>
int main(int argc, TCHAR *argv[]){

    LPOFSTRUCT _buffer;
    HFILE _hfile_ = OpenFile("E:\\mozunit.txt", _buffer, OF_READ);
    LPVOID _buffer_read;
    LPDWORD _bytes_read;
    bool flag = ReadFile(_buffer, _buffer_read, 5, _bytes_read, NULL);
    CloseHandle(_buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Now, when I run this I get an error that I have not initialized the `_buffer`. So to counter that I initialized `_buffer` like this:

```
LPOFSTRUCT _buffer = NULL;
```

Which gives me an access violation error. Why is that?

Comment: So I read your reference page, and it says nowhere that `NULL` is a valid value for the requested buffer.

Comment: A couple of the answers correctly point out the problem.  In addition, note that OpenFile has been deprecated for a long time.  You should be using CreateFile.  Despite its name, CreateFile can open an existing file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365430%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the second argument is...

> A pointer to the `OFSTRUCT` structure that receives information about a file when it is first opened.

By setting it to `NULL` you're attempting to write to memory with the address of zero.

Try this instead:

```
OFSTRUCT buffer;
HFILE hfile = OpenFile("E:\\mozunit.txt", &buffer, OF_READ);
char buffer_read[6];
DWORD bytes_read = 0;
bool flag = ReadFile(hfile, &buffer_read, 5, &bytes_read, NULL);
CloseHandle(hfile);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass a pointer to an allocated `LPOFSTRUCT` object to `OpenFile`.  You are passing `NULL` to a function that expects a valid memory, not NULL.  You declare an `OFSTRUCT` object and pass a pointer to it to `OpenFile`

You have the same issue for the parameters that you pass in `ReadFile`.  And you need to call `CloseFile` on the `_hFile_` file handle, not on the `_buffer`.  The same goes for `ReadFile` Finally you shouldn't be using `OpenFile` anyway - you should be using `CreateFile` as the documentation states.

Your code should be something more like:

```
#include "Tchar.h"
#include <windows.h>
int main(int argc, TCHAR *argv[]){

    OFSTRUCT _buffer = {0};  // Create an OFSTRUCT structure local variable and initialize it to zero.
    HFILE _hfile_ = OpenFile("E:\\mozunit.txt", &_buffer, OF_READ);
    char _buffer_read[5];
    DWORD _bytes_read;
    bool flag = ReadFile(_hfile_ , _buffer_read, 5, &_bytes_read, NULL);
    CloseHandle(_hfile_ );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this run on your system? I can't get to pass `_hfile_` to ReadFile.

Comment: `_hfile_` may be reserved. Try `hfile` instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/228783/78845 for more information.